# The elastica problem of Euler, Bernoulli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, plane-curves

In a book by Cash et al, I see the mention of the so-called Elastica problem (pg 221 in the link [here](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Documents/Solving_Differential_Equations_In_R_Soetaert_K.pdf)).

The problem is presented as a system of ODEs,

$$
x' = \cos (\phi) 
$$

$$
y' = \sin (\phi) 
$$

$$
\phi' = \kappa
$$

$$
\kappa' = F \cos (\phi)
$$

and when I looked for where these ODEs come from I could not find a clear derivation anywhere. There are references to Bernoulli, Euler, but the formulation looked different. Does anyone know a book, reference that shows where these equations come from?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps better asked at hsm.SE.

Comment: at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/? history and science of math? hmm

Comment: I've seen a buch of elastica question here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965043/elastica-numerical-check, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339037/the-elastica-problem-of-euler-bernoulli, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840683/deriving-the-bending-energy-equation-for-eulers-elastica that's why I came here.. but maybe another place is better

Comment: There is a footnote with a link that may give more information, but I don't have permission to follow it. Perhaps someone else does?

Comment: Which footnote? Which book?